# A way to evaluate a threshold without using if statements

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, negative-number

I have data being taken from a source such that if the value is above 2^13 (8192), the values are actually negative. Is there a way to do the following transition without using an if statement such as:

```
int data[SIZE]
for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
  if (data[i] > 8191)
    data[i] = data[i]-16384;
```

or

```
int data[SIZE]
for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
  if (data[i] > 8191)
    data[i] = ~(data[i] + 1 8292;
```

Any help eliminating the if statement without increasing the run time beyond O(n) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you would have to add at least n if statements to go beyond O(n) :)

Comment: What is the problem with the `if` statement? You can replace it with `?:` operator, but it just makes it more verbose.

Comment: what about `data[i] = - (data[i] - 8192);` ?

Comment: If this is for performance, can SSE2 be considered too? That would also make doing this without `if` a bit cleaner

Answer (score 0):

No. IF statements are one of the fundamental operations of a computer. A lot of effort has already been put into making them really, really fast.

**Don’t waste time prematurely micro-optimizing stuff.**

Write your application, then ***profile, profile, profile.*** Once you have hard data about where your application is slow, spend time optimizing *that*.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the following would not be compiled to a branch but a cmov:

```
int data[SIZE];

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
  auto d = data[i];
  auto v = d - 16384;
  auto condition = d > 8191;

  data[i] = condition ? v : d;
}
```

I'm sure a good optimising compiler wouldn't need it spelling out like this.

As has been noted, there are more ways to do this in SSE2 and also using SSE4 blending.

Comment: Using "?" is the same as if.

Comment: @Goswin von Brederlow, yes, you could add an `if` in my code and it wouldn't change the point I'm making or the compiled output. The `?` isn't really the enabler here, it's re-arranging the code to highlight setting up for the cmov - which as I've said will probably happen anyway with a decent compiler.

Answer (score 0):

First check the compiler output if your code even generates a branch. The compiler might be smart enough to optimize this in surprising ways.

Second, assuming 2th complement, you can do the following (strictly speaking this is undefined behaviour):

data[i] = (((int16_t)data[i]) << 5) >> 5;

Answer (score 0):

You could use [movfuscator](https://github.com/xoreaxeaxeax/movfuscator), which is a C compiler that constructs the whole binary out of x86 mov instructions, so no branching instructions would be used :D